# Why does Saxon delete blank lines in an identity transform?

Tags: xslt, saxon

Consider this "identity" transform:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="yes" media-type="application/xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

and this input XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Foobar xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:transform version="2.0">

      <!-- Parameters -->
      <xsl:param name="param1"/>
      <xsl:param name="param2"/>
      <xsl:param name="param3"/>

      <!-- Variables -->
      <xsl:variable name="variable1" select="'abc'"/>

      <xsl:template match="/*">
      </xsl:template>

   </xsl:transform>
</Foobar>
```

Why does SaxonJ-HE 11.3 delete the blank lines?

Here's a diff showing what I'm talking about:

```
$ saxon -xsl:transform.xsl -s:input.xml | diff -u input.xml -
--- input.xml   2022-06-16 16:26:41.000000000 -0400
+++ -   2022-06-16 16:28:42.000000000 -0400
@@ -6,12 +6,9 @@
       <xsl:param name="param1"/>
       <xsl:param name="param2"/>
       <xsl:param name="param3"/>
-
       <!-- Variables -->
       <xsl:variable name="variable1" select="'abc'"/>
-
       <xsl:template match="/*">
       </xsl:template>
-
    </xsl:transform>
 </Foobar>
```

Comment: If you expect the identity I would not use `indent="yes"` though I would need to check exactly what causes Saxon with that setting to seemingly lose lines.

Comment: You're correct. Let's assume the document is already properly indented (as in the example). In that case then I'd expect the transform to not change anything.

Comment: Note also that not ALL blank lines are being deleted; for example the one before the `<!-- Parameters -->` comment is not. So the behavior is both annoying AND inconsistent :)

Comment: Take off the `indent="yes"` and I think you get the result you expect. The spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#xml-indent speaks about whitespace to be "elided" or "replaced", as I said, I would need a closer look to tell whether the observed behaviour with `indent="yes"` makes sense. Probably easier to just wait what Michael Kay is going to answer.

Comment: I have had a quick read through that section, it is clear that you should go with `indent="no"` if you don't want any changes. I am afraid I have no clear explanation for the eliding you observe with `indent="yes"`, hard to tell what influences that. Wait for Michael Kay to answer or comment.

Comment: The question to ask is why do you care? Do you have some solution not treating XML as XML and trying to process it as strings?

Comment: The reason to care is because humans also read this particular XML document (also why we indent it in the first place). Blank lines, like indentation, help make it more readable for humans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite challenging to find an indentation algorithm that both (a) preserves existing whitespace in the source document, and (b) produces nice-looking output. For example, consider what happens when a template rule processes all children of an element (both element children and whitespace text node children) with an `xsl:sort` on an attribute value; if all whitespace from this output sequence is preserved, this will tend to put a massive wadge of whitespace at the start of the output sequence, which looks pretty ugly. This can also happen if you apply-templates to all children, but delete some of the elements while leaving the text nodes unchanged. So the spec allows the processor not only to add whitespace for indentation, but to merge ("elide") this with existing whitespace.

In particular, it's a reasonable assumption to make that if you get multiple blank lines in the result tree, they weren't put there deliberately, but arrived by accident as a result of copying multiple whitespace nodes from the input.

What's actually happening in this particular case is as follows:

- For comments, the rules are different depending on whether the comment follows a start tag or an end tag. The first comment follows a start tag, and in this case the accumulated whitespace is output as-is, followed by the comment with no further indentation. The second comment follows an end tag (actually an empty element tag), and in this case the comment is indented according to its hierarchic level in the result tree, and any preceding whitespace in the result tree is discarded.
- Before a start tag, indentation is added if the start tag immediately follows another start tag or end tag; if it follows a text node, no identation is added. This rule is designed primarily to make mixed content work properly.
- Before an end tag, indentation is added if it follows another end tag, but not if it follows a start tag or character data.

The detail is a lot more complex, and it has evolved in a fairly ad-hoc way to cope reasonably well with a wide variety of circumstances. As a high-level summary, Saxon will in some circumstances output the whitespace that it finds in the result tree, and in other circumstances it will output its own whitespace in preference. The algorithm isn't perfect, but it copes reasonably well with messy situations like when the input is indented with 4 spaces and the output is to be indented with 3.